# Unexpected Output In Shared Memory Program

Tags: c, server, client, output, shared-memory

I have a server that creates some shared memory space and puts "hello world" in it & a client that is supposed to look at that shared memory space and print out "hello world" to the console accordingly; however, instead I'm just getting a "*" character & the server isn't terminating as it is supposed to. Below is the code, any insight as to how I can fix this is appreciated.

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>


#define SHSIZE 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int shmid;
    key_t key;
    char *shm;
    char *s;

    key = 9876;

    shmid = shmget(key, SHSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (shmid < 0)
    {
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);
    }

    shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    if (shm == (char *) -1)
    {
            perror("shmat");
            exit(1);
    }

    memcpy(shm, "Hello World", 11);

    s = shm;
    s += 11;

    *s = 0;

    while (*shm != '*')
    {
            sleep(1);
    }

    shmdt (shm); // detach
    shmctl (shmid, IPC_RMID, 0); //deallocate
    return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>


#define SHSIZE 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int shmid;
    key_t key;
    char *shm;
    char *s;

    key = 9876;

    shmid = shmget(key, SHSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (shmid < 0)
    {
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);
    }

    shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    if (shm == (char *) -1)
    {
            perror("shmat");
            exit(1);
    }

    for (s = shm; *s != 0; s++)
    {
            printf("%c", *s);
    }

    printf("\n");

    *shm = '*';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your programm on one of the opensuse 42.1 box running with gcc version

gcc version 4.8.5 (SUSE Linux) and following is the output. your programm is fine and giving the output as expected. Follow the below details.

```
/WorkDir/checks/stackover> gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -o unx_sh_server  unx_sh_server.c 
unx_sh_server.c: In function ‘main’:
unx_sh_server.c:12:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
          ^
unx_sh_server.c:12:26: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
                      ^
/WorkDir/checks/stackover> gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -o unx_sh_client unx_sh_client.c 
unx_sh_client.c: In function ‘main’:
unx_sh_client.c:11:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
          ^
unx_sh_client.c:11:26: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])

/WorkDir/checks/stackover> ls -rlt
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 progra users   761 Feb 15 09:29 unx_sh_server.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 progra users   643 Feb 15 09:29 unx_sh_client.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 progra users 12768 Feb 15 09:30 unx_sh_server
-rwxr-xr-x 1 progra users 12664 Feb 15 09:30 unx_sh_client
/WorkDir/checks/stackover> ./unx_sh_server &
[1] 12180
/WorkDir/checks/stackover> 
/WorkDir/checks/stackover> 
/WorkDir/checks/stackover> ./unx_sh_client 
Hello World
/WorkDir/checks/stackover> fg
bash: fg: job has terminated`enter code here`
[1]+  Done                    ./unx_sh_server
/WorkDir/checks/stackover>
```

Please check the way you run the client and server.